# Why can I connect through SSH without using the required private key?

Tags: ssh

I am trying to connect to a server through SSH, using a private key that is required for the connection to succeed.

```
ssh -i <path-to-my-private-key> <user>@<server-ip>
```

It works. However, even if I don't use the private key, or if I use the wrong one, it works too, while it should not. Why does it work?

Comment: If you mean you can successfully log in to your server by running `ssh ubuntu@<my-ec2-url>` without using the `-i <path-to-my-private-key>` option, it may be that you are running `ssh-agent`, which caches private keys in memory.

Comment: Your private key is being supplied by default, perhaps because you have a `host *` entry in `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: @larsks thanks that was it. I must have used `ssh-agent` while following a tutorial, and I didn't take the time to understand what it does.

Comment: @jarmod I don't have a `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: OK, we know now it's ssh-agent, but it could have been `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: My question is actually way too specific since it has nothing to do with AWS. Should I rewrite the question in a simpler way an @larsks writes his comment as an answer for it? I haven't seen any question on SO that looked like this one.

Comment: @jarmod yes indeed. It would be interesting to write this possibility in the answer.

Comment: Question is fine as is, imo, but @larsks should write up the answer to get credit.

Comment: I edited it anyway because some people seem to think it's a bad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you can successfully log in to your server by running `ssh ubuntu@<my-ec2-url>` without using the `-i <path-to-my-private-key>` option, it is likely that you are running `ssh-agent`.

`ssh-agent` caches private keys in memory so that they can be used for authentication without having to enter the password on every connection.

---

As @jarmod points out, it is also possible that you have configured a private key for your target host in your `~/.ssh/config` file.  For example:

```
Host my-ec2-url
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/something-not-named-id_rsa
```

...although this is less likely, because unless you had created an unprotected private key, this would still prompt you for a key passphrase (and it would obviously need to match the public keys you have configured on the remote host).